# Sympy count_ops returning incorrect result?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, algebra

I'm doing a simple test with sympy (python=3.10, sympy=1.12) and I don't understand why the result seems wrong (results below):

Code:

```
from sympy import *
x0, x1, x2 = symbols('x0 x1 x2')
print(count_ops(2 * (x0 + x1) * x2, visual=True))
```

Result:

```
Add + 3*MUL
```

I would expect 2 multiplications and 1 add... Any ideas on what I'm missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an expression is being build, SymPy applies some manipulations. In this simple case, there is a number, `2`, that multiplies and addition, `x0 + x1`. SymPy does the following: `2*x0 + 2*x1`, then it multiplies it by `x2`.

```py
expr = 2 * (x0 + x1) * x2
print(expr, "\t", count_ops(expr))
# out: x2*(2*x0 + 2*x1)      4
```

As you can see, you have 3 multiplications and one addition, for a total of 4 operations. Let's change the order of terms:

```py
expr = (x0  + x1) * 2 * x2
print(expr, "\t", count_ops(expr))
# out: x2*(2*x0 + 2*x1)      4
```

Same result as before, because you have an addition that multiplies an integer number. Let's change again the order of terms:

```py
expr = 2 * x2 * (x0 + x1)
print(expr, "\t", count_ops(expr))
# out: 2*x2*(x0 + x1)    3
```

One addition and two multiplications. Since you have a symbol that multiply the addition, no manipulations were applied.

Answer (score 0):

@David_sd has given the answer. Python builds a product from left to right. If ever a sum and a Rational need to be multiplied, the Rational is distributed. There have been attempts to change this but it is not an easy change to make since there are many aspects of SymPy operations that assume that this is taking place. It is just something to be aware of at this point and, if you don't want it to happen, you have to make an uneveluated product `Mul(2, x + y, evaluate=False)` or when there are more than 2 arguments, put the Rational last, e.g. `(x + 1)*(y + 1)*2` or make sure it and the sum are not the first two arguments, e.g. `2*x*(y + 1)`.